# Unsupported session configuration (React Native and ARKit)

Tags: xcode, react-native, arkit

I'm having an issue with a library designed to integrate ARKit with react native components (https://github.com/react-native-ar/react-native-arkit). I'm also using a react native camera component on another screen (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera), but during certain sequences of switching between the two, I get the following error:

```
userInfo: 
NSLocalizedDescription: "Unsupported capture session configuration."
NSLocalizedFailureReason: "Input device and/or format of the provided capture session are not supported for the given configuration."
NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion: "Make sure that the correct device and format are being used for capture."
```

This only happens when switching in the following order:

ARKit (works fine here) --> RNCamera --> ARKit (fails here)

Whereas sequences like this work fine:

ARKit . --> screen without RNCamera --> ARKit

RNCamera --> ARKit --> screen without RNCamera --> ARKit

The react native camera component works fine no matter the order, and I'm using an iPhone 8 for development. Let me know if you need any other info to debug, any help is appreciated!